# Sharepoint List Form Javascript get validation results

Tags: javascript, list-form, validation

Is it possible to find out using javascript/jquery if a SharePoint 2013 new/edit list form throws validation errors?

Something like:

```
if(page.ValidationFailed)
//do something
```

I do not won't to write my own custom validators (e.g. PreSaveItem-method). I just need to know if the (serverside?) validation has failed and in best case which element has thrown the validation error.